# freeradius sql_session_start not working using google ldap

Tags: freeradius

radius won't insert any data in radacct database, only on radpostauth.
Already enabled in sites-enabled/default and mods-config/sql/main/mysql/queries.conf

Answer (score 0):

radacct table is for accounting data, you must setup your supplicants to send accounting to your freeradius